# BeautifulSoup не находит тэг

Tags: python, tkinter, requests, beautiful-soup

```
# imports
from tkinter import *
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# requests
r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BA+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB.+%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E&oq=%D0%9A%D1%83&aqs=chrome.1.69i59l2j69i57j69i59l2j69i61l3.2591j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
ds_course_tag =  soup.findAll("span", {"class": "DFlfde SwHCTb"})
# root
sd = Tk()

sd.geometry("300x500")
sd.title("Калькулятор валют")
sd.resizable(False, False)

def clear():
    rub_entry.delete(0, END)
    dollar_entry.delete(0, END)

def count():

    # dollar_course = float(dollar_course_entry.get())
    #logic
    if rub_entry.get() == "":
        rub = float(dollar_entry.get())*dollar_course
        rub = round(rub, 3)
        rub_entry.delete(0, END)
        rub_entry.insert(END, rub)
        
        
    elif dollar_entry.get() == "":
        dollar = float(rub_entry.get())//dollar_course
        dollar = round(dollar, 3)
        dollar_entry.delete(0, END)
        dollar_entry.insert(END, dollar)

# elements

# dollar_course_label = Label(text="Курс доллара")
# dollar_course_label.place(x=80, y=75)

# dollar_course_entry = Entry()
# dollar_course_entry.place(x=80, y=100)


dollar_label = Label(text="Доллары")
dollar_label.place(x=80, y=225)

dollar_entry = Entry()
dollar_entry.place(x=80, y=250)


rub_label = Label(text="Рубли")
rub_label.place(x=80, y=275)

rub_entry = Entry()
rub_entry.place(x=80, y=300)


counter = Button(text="Рассчитать", command=count)
counter.place(x=80, y=400)

clearer = Button(text="Очистить", command=clear)
clearer.place(x=80, y=450)

sd.bind("<Return>", lambda x: count())

sd.mainloop()
```

Я пробовал разные сайты, но не выходило.
Это конвертер валют, он должен брать курс доллара к бел. рублю из интернета, но не получилось.

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: посмотрите r.text

Comment: у гугла названия классов динамические, изменяются о вызова к вызову

Comment: @Jack_oS а как тогда это исправить?

Comment: взять курс из [официального источника](https://www.nbrb.by/bel/statistics/rates/ratesdaily.asp), там table class="currencyTable" вряд ли поменяется ;)

Comment: @Jack_oS Не работает, там none

Comment: где "там"? ....

Comment: @Jack_oS ну в переменной куда я достаю

Comment: [тут](https://www.nbrb.by/bel/statistics/rates/ratesdaily.asp)? а код вы поменяли под другой сайт или тем же парсите?